# custom function in module returns page not found

Tags: php, opencart

Im tying to build a module for opencart 2 and 3 but im having a strange problem. On my admin side i have the below code (I have shorten the code to explain the issue).

```
class ControllerExtensionModuleAddNewOrderItems extends Controller {
    private $type = 'module';
    private $name = 'add_new_order_items';

    public function index() {
        echo "this is index";
     }

    public function hello() {
        echo "hello";
    }

}
```

It has 2 functions index and hello, the problem is when i call the index function it shows the output but when call the function hello it gives me a 404 error. What ever function i add apart from index, it gives me a page not found error.

There is no errors in the log and im using PHP 7.1 in my hosting.

Can someone let me know what might be causing the problem?

Comment: How you call to function hello?

Comment: Please provide the URL you used for calling the above functions.

Comment: To see a full code of calling (or even a full controller) would be grade.